# Find Shortest Binary String In Given Interval

Tags: javascript, algorithm, language-agnostic, binary

Say I have two values `0 <= a < b <= 1`, how can I chose an `x` such that `a <= x`**`<`**`b` with the shortest binary expansion possible?

My approach so far is to take the binary strings of `a` and `b`, with the decimal point removed, and at the first place they differ, take the expansion of `a` up until that point. If there's more of `a` to consume, strip the last bit. Finally, add `1`.

In JavaScript:

```
var binaryInInterval = function(a, b) {
  if (a < 0 || b > 1 || a >= b) return undefined;

  var i, u, v, x = '';

  a = a.toString(2).replace('.', '');
  b = b.toString(2).replace('.', '');

  for (i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    u = parseInt(a.substr(i, 1), 10) || 0;
    v = parseInt(b.substr(i, 1), 10) || 0;

    x += u.toString();
    if (u != v) { 
      if (i + 1 < a.length) x = x.slice(0, -1);
      x += '1';
      break;
    }
  }

  return '0.' + x.substr(1);
};
```

This works, but I'm not convinced that it's *generally* correct. Any thoughts?...

---

**EDIT** I've already found a case that doesn't work correctly :P

```
binaryInInterval(0.25, 0.5) = '0.1'

0.25  0.01
0.5   0.1
        ^ Difference
          but a hasn't been fully consumed
          so we strip 00 to 0 before adding 1
```

---

**EDIT 2** An alternative algorithm would be to iterate through `2^-n` and check if any multiple of this fits within the interval. This would be more expensive, however.

Comment: How is this javascript and language-agnostic?

Comment: I've implemented the algorithm in JavaScript, for illustrative purposes. I'm interested in the algorithm's correctness, rather than its implementation in any particular language.

Comment: if (i + 1 < a.length) x = x.slice(0, -1); Could you explain please?

Comment: @closure This line strips the last bit from `x` if there's still more of `a` to consume.

Comment: "how can I chose an x such that a <= x<b with the shortest binary expansion possible?" <--- is that a typo? I mean: with 'a<=x', wouldn't 'a' always be the right answer? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Polmonite Good point: I should have made it clearer. We want to choose `x` with the shortest binary representation. If we have `a = 0.1` and `b = 0.25`, then in binary, `a = 0.000(1100)`, so a better choice would be `x = 0.001` (i.e., 1/8).

Comment: (1/256, 1/2) == (0.00000001, 0.1) => Answer 1/256 (0.00000001). Is it correct?

Comment: @closure Yes: In the special case of `a = 2^(-n)`, for some `n`, then we can take `x = a`

Comment: Actually, @closure, a better solution would be `x = 1/4` as it's within the bounds and has a shorter length (0.01 vs. 0.00000001).

Comment: I have been fascinated with the problem and would love to understand the reasoning better. Would you be able to share a few links? I will post code in a little while with understanding I have on this.

Comment: Thanks for your input @closure. The ultimate purpose to this is to choose a solution in the [arithmetic coding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding). I'm teaching myself how this works and my encoder successfully generates an interval, but I'm having trouble picking the best point inside: 'best' meaning 'shortest' because it's a compression algorithm, after all!

Comment: @Xophmeister: Glad to be of some help. I got interested in learning it myself. Please let me know if code has short-comings in certain cases. I will be happy to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function bin(a, b) {
 var den = 1;
 while (true) {
  var bint = Math.floor(b);
  if (bint == b) bint--;
  if (a <= bint) {
   return bint / den;
  }
  den *= 2;
  a *= 2;
  b *= 2;
 }
}
```

The code iterates through larger and larger power-of-two denominators (`den`) until it finds one that supports a value that fits in the range.

Comment: Very nice, +1. Nitpick: The OP's example code suggests the return value should be a string containing the actual binary expansion (though I'd argue it makes more sense to return a number, given that both parameters are numbers).

Comment: @j_random_hacker A little `toString(2)` action changes the return value to a string, though I agree that returning a string doesn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: Changed to accepted, as it's simpler to understand. It's probably faster than all those string manipulations, too! Thanks :)

Comment: BTW: The string output is for the sake of the view; however, I agree that number -- at least internally -- is better.

Answer (score 4):

It will fail for inputs like a = 0.1, b = 0.100001 (in binary -- i.e. a = 0.5, b = 0.515625 in decimal).  The correct answer would be 0.1 in this case, but your algorithm will produce 0.11 instead, which is not only not minimal-length, but greater than b :-(

Your digit-checking looks fine to me -- the problem is that when you have made the (right) decision to end the loop, you construct the wrong output if b's digit string is longer.  One easy way to fix it would be to output digits one-at-a-time, as you go along: until you see a different character, you know you must include the current character.

One more tip: I don't know Javascript well, but I think both `parseInt()` calls are unnecessary, since nothing you do with `u` or `v` actually requires arithmetic.

**[EDIT]**

Here is some example digit-at-a-time code that incorporates a few other considerations:

```
var binaryInInterval = function(a, b) {
  if (a < 0 || b > 1 || a >= b) return undefined;

  if (a == 0) return '0';  // Special: only number that can end with a 0

  var i, j, u, v, x = '';

  a = a.toString(2).replace('.', '');
  b = b.toString(2).replace('.', '');

  for (i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    u = a.substr(i, 1);
    v = b.substr(i, 1);

    if (u != v) {
      // We know that u must be '0' and v must be '1'.
      // We therefore also know that u must have at least 1 more '1' digit,
      // since you cannot have a '0' as the last digit.
      if (i < b.length - 1) {
        // b has more digits, meaning it must
        // have more '1' digits, meaning it must be larger than
        // x if we add a '1' here, so it's safe to do that and stop.
        x += '1';     // This is >= a, because we know u = '0'.
      } else {
        // To ensure x is >= a, we need to look for the first
        // '0' in a from this point on, change it to a '1',
        // and stop.  If a only contains '1's from here on out,
        // it suffices to copy them, and not bother appending a '1'.
        x += '0';
        for (j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
          if (a.substr(j, 1) == '0') {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      break;  // We're done.  Fall through to fix the binary point.
    } else {
      x += u;    // Business as usual.
    }
  }

  // If we make it to here, it must be because either (1) we hit a
  // different digit, in which case we have prepared an x that is correct
  // except for the binary point, or (2) a and b agree on all
  // their leftmost min(len(a), len(b)) digits.  For (2), it must therefore be
  // that b has more digits (and thus more '1' digits), because if a
  // had more it would necessarily be larger than b, which is impossible.
  // In this case, x will simply be a.
  // So in both cases (1) and (2), all we need to do is fix the binary point.
  if (x.length > 1) x = '0.' + x.substr(1);
  return x;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Could you please expand it somewhat: I don't really see what context your suggested fix should be applied to? (The `parseInt` was a relic from former attempts, when I was doing bit twiddling and checking for falseiness!)

Comment: @Xophmeister: I've added some (untested) Javascript digit-at-a-time code. Notice that we now only loop till the *minimum* length. In writing this I hit upon a corner case I hadn't thought of -- the case where a is longer than b and they disagree on b's last digit needs special attention!  E.g. a = 0.011011110111001, b = 0.0111 should have the answer x = 0.011011111.

Comment: Nice one, @j_random_hacker Your algorithm works except for when `a = 0` or `b = 1`. I'll see if I can tease those out... Otherwise, consider this accepted :)

Comment: ...Changing your initialisation of `x` and `i` and the normalisation of `a` and `b` (i.e., removing the decimal point) back to how I had originally defined them fixes that problem :)

Comment: @Xophmeister: Whoops, I think those are fixed now. But I notice closure's code uses `!==` and `===` for some comparisons -- you might want to check whether my use of `!=` and `==` is correct.

Comment: Those won't be a problem: `===` and `!==` are just the type safe versions of the respective comparators. Since we're mixing strings and numbers, it might actually be safer to therefore use the less 'safe' versions.

Comment: @Xophmeister: I see Raymond Chen has added an answer that is much smaller and simpler, and passes all the tests I can think of. If I were you I'd make that the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

I am posting another version of the code. That tries to fix the known issues:

```
  var binaryInIntervalNew = function(inpA, inpB) {

    if (inpA < 0 || inpB > 1 || inpA >= inpB) return undefined;

    var i, u, v, x = '';

    a = inpA.toString(2).split('.');
    b = inpB.toString(2).split('.');

    a = a[a.length - 1];
    b = b[b.length - 1];

    for (i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); i++) {

      u = a.substr(i, 1);
      v = b.substr(i, 1);

      if (u !== v) {
        // x cannot become equal to b, let us verify that
        if ((i+1) === b.length) {
          x += '01';
        } else {
          x += '1';
        }
        break;
      } else {
        x += u;
      }
      // console.log("x: " + x + " i:" + i);
    }

    x = '0.' + x;
    return parseFloat(x);
  };
```

A short function to test both functions:

```
function bin(a, b) {
  console.log("a:" + a.toString(2));
  console.log("b:" + b.toString(2));
  if (binaryInIntervalNew) console.log("binaryInIntervalNew: " + binaryInIntervalNew(a, b));
  if (binaryInInterval) console.log("binaryInInterval: " + binaryInInterval(a, b));
}
```

Now few results:

```
bin(1/16, 1/4);
a:0.0001 
b:0.01
binaryInIntervalNew: 0.001
binaryInInterval: 0.01

bin(.1, .2);
a:0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101 
b:0.001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
binaryInIntervalNew: 0.001
binaryInInterval: 0.001

bin(1/4, 1/2);
a:0.01 b:0.1
b:0.1
binaryInIntervalNew: 0.01
binaryInInterval: 0.1

bin(.2, .5);
a:0.001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101 b:0.1
b:0.1
binaryInIntervalNew: 0.01
binaryInInterval: 0.1

bin(.0011, .1);
a:0.00000000010010000001011011110000000001101000110110111000101111 b:0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
b:0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
binaryInIntervalNew: 0.0001
binaryInInterval: 0.0001
```

Comment: @ Xophmeister: Please have a look and let me know if something missing. I have tried incorporating solution to all the issues that I have gathered here.

Comment: I believe this will fail for e.g. a = 0.0011, b = 0.1. When b is shorter than a and different on its last digit, you need to scan through the rest of a, looking for its first 0 (see my code).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: The answer is 0.0001. Both original and new algoritms get the same answer. What do you get with your algoritm?

Comment: When `a = 0.0011` and `b = 0.1`, one would expect a solution of `0.01`.

Comment: @Xophmeister: I think in your above statement a and b are in binary, while what j_random_hacker had put were decimal. Let me test this and update the result for your test case.

Comment: I intended my numbers to be in binary too -- sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @j_random_hacker: The answer is .01 from my algorithm too for binary.  Let me think of more test cases.

Comment: Oh dear, more confusion caused by me -- sorry! I meant a = 0.011, b = 0.1 (both numbers in binary). The answer to that should be 0.011, but I think your algorithm will produce 0.01, which is < a. Also if a = 0.01101 and b = 0.1, the answer should be 0.0111, but your algorithm will produce 0.01 again.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You are absolutely correct. I have failed to handle this case in the zeal of keeping the length short.